# What Microsoft tSql code will create "Group Identifiers" for groups of rows delimited by a 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```html
--drop table GroupIdentifierTest
go
Create table GroupIdentifierTest
(
RowId varchar(10),
[Delimiter] int
)

insert into GroupIdentifierTest
select 'a', 0 union all
select 'b', 0 union all
select 'c', 0 union all
select 'd', 1 union all
select 'e', 0 union all
select 'f', 1
select * from GroupIdentifierTest
delete GroupIdentifierTest
insert into GroupIdentifierTest
select 'a', 1 union all
select 'b', 1 union all
select 'c', 1 union all
select 'd',  2 union all
select 'e', 2 union all
select 'f', 2
select r.RowId, r.Delimiter As GroupId from GroupIdentifierTest r
```

If you have a rowset, and the data is in groupings, indicated by a column value of 1,  how can you generate GroupId numbers?

In this example, the first rowset needs to be transformed into the second rowset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many groups do you need? Perhaps this will help:

```
WITH prep AS
(
  SELECT RowId, delimiter, GroupId = NTILE(2) OVER (ORDER BY RowID)
  FROM GroupIdentifierTest
)
UPDATE prep
SET delimiter = GroupId;

SELECT RowId, Delimiter AS groupID 
FROM GroupIdentifierTest;
```

Results:

```
RowId      groupID
---------- -----------
a          1
b          1
c          1
d          2
e          2
f          2
```

Comment: NTILE delivered correct results for the example, but will not work in my scenario because the group boundaries are seldom equally dispersed.  The number of groups varies as well.  It's funny how difficult it was to solve this scenario.  In my case, the solution was to change the group boundary delimiter to be placed at the beginning of the group instead of the end.  Then it is just a matter of using SUM() OVER.